# Unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR`on`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

in the below block, and cannot seem to figure out why seeing as there are no unclosed quotes.

```
<?php 

  include("something.php"); 

  $somepage="somepage.html";
  $apple=$_POST["apple"];
  $banana=$_POST["banana"];
  $orange=$_POST["orange"];
  $email=$_POST["email"];

  $connection=$conn; #conn is from something.php

  define("someSQL","INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE, EMAIL) VALUES ('$apple', '$banana', '$orange', '$email'); 

  $conninfo=oci_parse($connection,bbsSQL);
  oci_execute($conninfo);

  $to      = $email;
  $subject = 'Subject';
  $message = '<html><body>Hello</body></html>';
  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: Somewhere' . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  oci_free_statement($personinfo);
  oci_close($personcon);

  echo "An email has been sent.<br>";
  echo "Return to the <a href=$somepage>home page</a>.";


?>.
```

Might anybody know of why this is the case?

Comment: This isn't enough code to reproduce that error. Something else is causing this; show full code.

Comment: What I have been able to reproduce that error is using `$email = "email@example.com;` <= notice the missing quote? So, a missing quote somewhere. So again, show full code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've added the bulk of it.

Comment: You are missing a closing quote on your SQL definition. This question is about a typo, it should be closed.

Comment: @Sorin That appears to have been the culprit, thanks!

Comment: `define("someSQL","INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE, EMAIL) VALUES ('$apple', '$banana', '$orange', '$email')";` that would have been settled 24 mins. ago had you posted full code right away. I knew it was a missing quote somewhere, as per [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739415/unexpected-t-ns-separator#comment40244859_25739415) 16 mins. ago / prior to this. Given the posted code.

Comment: Use a syntax highlighting editor, it should have been obvious that after the SQL, lines are part of a string, that was how I've seen it in the above sample.

Comment: Actually a missing quote **and** a bracket `define("someSQL","INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE, EMAIL) VALUES ('$apple', '$banana', '$orange', '$email')");`

Answer (score -2):

Try not to mix the two string indicators (`'` and `"`). Change the string seperators around `"\r\n"` to single-quotes (apostrophe) characters - that should solve the problem.

Also, in this situation there really isn't any point in closing your string literal and then appending the line break to it in this manner, you could just go with:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

****Edit**:

Based on your edit, the following line is missing some characters:

```
define("someSQL","INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE, EMAIL) VALUES ('$apple', '$banana', '$orange', '$email');
```

You are missing `")` just before the closing semicolon. That basically means PHP is taking all the stuff after that row as part of the string, however your doublequotes just around the `\r\n` part were falsely closing that string.

Comment: Mixing single quotes and double quotes when concatenating strings is no problem, and perfectly valid, especially when writing special characters like "\r" which are simply not translated when using single quotes.

Comment: Oddly when I try going with your coded suggestion, I get `unexpected T_STRING` on `$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";`, and when changing the string operators around "\r\n", I received the same error (`unexpected T_STRING`) on an echo following the block.

Comment: @Alpine Are you not looking at the comments under your question?

Comment: @DanielAndre: valid addition. It did however shine light upon the probable fact that somewhere earlier there is an incorrectly closed string.

Comment: My comment seems more out of place after the edit, since the original comment only had the first paragraph, and that paragraph is still factually incorrect - changing double to single quotes around "\r\n" is the wrong answer. The other parts of that comment is good advice, hope you found the error.